# How can i switch between react components using framer motion?

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

In my react app i need to switch between components like in a carousel. I found this example to build an image carousel only using framer motion: https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-image-gallery-pqvx3?file=/src/Example.tsx:1715-1725

I want to adapt this to switching between components. At the moment my page looks something like this:

```js
const variants = {
  enter: (direction: number) => {
    return {
      x: direction > 0 ? 100 : -100,
      opacity: 0,
    }
  },
  center: {
    zIndex: 1,
    x: 0,
    opacity: 1,
  },
  exit: (direction: number) => {
    return {
      zIndex: 0,
      x: direction < 0 ? 100 : -100,
      opacity: 0,
    }
  },
}

const Page = () => {

const [[page, direction], setPage] = useState([0, 0])
const paginate = (newDirection: number) => {
  setPage([page + newDirection, newDirection])
}
return (
   <motion.div
     key={page}
     custom={direction}
     variants={variants}
     initial="enter"
     animate="center"
     exit="exit"
   >
     <!-- my components, between which I want to switch, should appear here -->
   </motion.div>
 )
}
```

how would I have to build the logic to be able to switch dynamic between my components (slides)? In the codesandbox example the images were changed via an array:

```js
const imageIndex = wrap(0, images.length, page);

<motion.img key={page} src={images[imageIndex]} />
```

How could i do that to switch between jsx elements?

**Edit**

The answer from Joshua Wootonn is correct, but you need to add the `custom` prop also to the `TestComp` to get the animation working with dynamic variants like this:

```js
const TestComp = ({ bg }: { bg: string }) => (
  <motion.div
    custom={direction}
    variants={variants}
    initial="enter"
    animate="center"
    exit="exit"
    transition={{
      x: { type: "spring", stiffness: 100, damping: 30 },
      opacity: { duration: 0.2 },
    }}
    className="absolute w-full h-full"
    style={{
      background: bg,
    }}
  />
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of things were missing from the above answer to get exit animations working.

1. If you want exit animations to work within AnimationPresense you need to set keys on its children

```
        <AnimatePresence initial={false} custom={direction}>
          {page === 0 && <TestComp key="0" bg="rgb(171, 135, 255)" />}
          {page === 1 && <TestComp key="1" bg="rgb(68, 109, 246)" />}
          {page === 2 && <TestComp key="2" bg="rgb(172, 236, 161)" />}
        </AnimatePresence>
```

2. If you want to animate something in while something is still animating out without having massive content shifting, you need to take them out of the flow. (use absolute positioning and wrap with relatively positioned container)

```
      <div style={{ position: "relative", height: "300px", width: "300px" }}>
        <AnimatePresence initial={false} custom={direction}>
          ...
        </AnimatePresence>
      </div>
```

and on the child components

```
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
```

Working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-carousel-animation-wetrf?file=/src/App.tsx:658-708

Comment: thank you for the correction. I've just noticed that too. One more question: Would it be possible to make the whole thing a bit more dynamic? Could i work with a `<Slide></Slide>` component instead of the conditional-rendering? A parent component would then automatically detect how many slides have been defined and create an array based on that?

Comment: The most dynamic way of doing this would be maintaining an array and mapping it directly inside of AnimatePresense. Because of the need for an explicit key, which is a limitation of React, they do have to be mapped directly within the AnimatePresense.


More details here: https://www.framer.com/api/motion/animate-presence/#animating-custom-components

Answer (score 1):

Use `<AbsencePresence>` with mode `wait` and initial set to false

```js
<AnimatePresence mode="wait" initial={false}>
  {itemKey === 0 && (
    <motion.div
      key="0"
      initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
      animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
      exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
    />
  )}
  {itemKey === 1 && (
    <motion.div
      key="1"
      initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
      animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
      exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
    />
  )}
</AnimatePresence>
```

Comment: This is better alternative rather than position: absolute;

Answer (score 0):

Your components should return `<motion.div>` (or `<motion.section>`, `<motion.span>` etc.).
And in the page component you should use `<AnimatePresence />` component (like in the example):

```
<AnimatePresence initial={false} custom={direction}>
  {COMPONENTS}
</AnimatePresence>
```

Then you have to decide which component will appear:

```
{page === 0 && <ComponentOne />}
{page === 1 && <ComponentTwo/>}
{page === 2 && <ComponentThree/>}
```

The animations you can control with `variants`.

You can see a quick demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-hypatia-7wqjc?file=/src/App.tsx